# VHDL Testbench code doesn't work for register

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I want to  simulate the register  logic , but  the test bench don't  working , when affect the input signal  "Si, ECi, Ri, Ci", all signal input fixed to "0000000001"  when I run the simulation in Xlinix , and Output fixed to "ZZZZZZZZ0" I don't know why?

Here's the code vhdl of register

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all; 
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity Registre is
    Generic ( N: positive :=10);
    Port ( R : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N downto 1);
           EC : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N downto 1); 
           C : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N downto 1);
           S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N downto 1);
           Vss : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N downto 1);
           Vdd : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N downto 1);
           DA : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N downto 1));
end Registre;

architecture Behavioral of Registre is

    component SA_REG 
        Port ( EC : in  STD_LOGIC;
               C : in  STD_LOGIC;
               R : in  STD_LOGIC;
               S : in  STD_LOGIC;
               Q : out  STD_LOGIC;
               Vss : in  STD_LOGIC;
               Vdd : in  STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    Component SA_REGDR
        Port ( R : in  STD_LOGIC;
               C : in  STD_LOGIC;
               EC : in  STD_LOGIC;
               Q : out  STD_LOGIC;
               Vss: in STD_LOGIC;
               Vdd: in STD_LOGIC
           );
    end component;

begin

    DR : SA_REGDR port map ( R=> R(10) ,EC=> EC(10), C=> C(10), Vss=> Vss(10), Vdd=> Vdd(10), Q=> DA(10) );

    Mgen : for i in 1 to N-1 generate
        M : SA_REG port map (R=>R(i), EC=> EC(i), C=> C(i),S=> S(i), Vss=> Vss(i), Vdd=> Vdd(i), Q=> DA(i) ); 
    end generate;

end Behavioral;
```

Test bench  :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity Registre_tb is
end Registre_tb;

architecture Behavioral of Registre_tb is
    component Registre
        generic( N : integer :=10);
        Port ( R : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1);
               EC : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1);
               C : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1);
               S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1);
               Vss : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1);
               Vdd : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1);
               DA : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1));
    end component;

    signal  Ri  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1):= (others => '0');
    signal  Ci  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1):= (others => '0');
    signal  ECi : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1):= (others => '0');
    signal  Si  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1):= (others => '0');
    signal  Vssi: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1):= (others => '0');
    signal  Vddi: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1):= (others => '1');
    signal  DAi : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1);

    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
begin
    -- instanciate 
    component_in_test : Registre port map( --instantiation of the Registre component
        R => Ri,
        C => Ci,
        EC => ECi,
        S => Si,
        Vss => Vssi,
        Vdd => Vddi,
        DA => DAi
    );

    -- stimulis 
    clk <= not clk after 1ns; --creates 100MHz clock inside testbench

    Ri_gen : process(clk) is   --process which will check Ri with every possible value
    begin
        if clk'Event and clk = '1' then
            Ri <= Ri + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    Ci_gen : process(clk) is   --process which will check Ci with every possible value
    begin
        if clk'Event and clk = '1' then
            Ci <= Ci + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    ECi_gen : process(clk) is   --process which will check ECi with every possible value
    begin
        if clk'Event and clk = '1' then
            ECi <= ECi + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    Si_gen : process(clk) is   --process which will check Si with every possible value
    begin
        if clk'Event and clk = '1' then
            Si <= Si + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Simulation 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the discussion of longest static prefix in the VHDL FAQ at:  http://www.eda.org/comp.lang.vhdl/FAQ1.html#drivers

For this reason, you need to re-write your instance as:

```
Mgen  : for i in 1 to N generate  
  If_N : if i = N generate
    DR : SA_REGDR port map ( R=> R(10) ,EC=> EC(10), C=> C(10), Vss=> Vss(10), Vdd=> Vdd(10), Q=> DA(10) ); 
  end generate ; 

  if_OTHERS : if i /= N generate
    M : SA_REG port map (R=>R(i), EC=> EC(i), C=> C(i),S=> S(i), Vss=> Vss(i), Vdd=> Vdd(i), Q=> DA(i) ); 
  end generate ; 
end generate;
```

Comment: thank you so much , it working now , by modification the instance , and fixe the signal 'Si to  1 "  signal  Si :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (10 downto 1):= (others => '1');' , but the error always arises at the output 10 " DA(10) it fixe at "Z"

Comment: I do not get it. All except bit 10 were mapped to SA_REG and it stays the same. What has changed? Bit 1 has switched 'z' => '0', as expected. What has changed?

Comment: no , the bit 10 who is mapped to Component SA_REGDR is  switched to 'Z'   , not the bit 1

Comment: Wait, bit 10 was already 'z', how can it switch to the state it already is? In your design, all bits are 'z' initially. After first clock, bit1 inputs have changed to 1 and you have got output '0' there. That is arguable. Why should we look for a flaw here? Why should I tell anything about bit 1 switching into 'z'? What does it all has to do with bit 10 and 'switching it into state 'z'?

Comment: I understand now thank you so much, I check the functioning  it is logic , i have other question ,  there are any explain when  the signal "Si" fixed to (others =>'0') all output are switched to 'Z', expect the output 0,? my best  regards

Comment: @user3212448 I am glad that you understand it now. I want Jim (I know, he is the most prominent VHDL specification expert in the world) to answer what was achieved with his proposal. I have told you that you need to reveal the implementation of SA_REG and SA_REGDR to answer the Si => DA dependency. I have told that in my answer. I do not understand why it was deleted.

Comment: @Val  Not seeing the rest code, I thought the issue was either enables or longest static prefix.  You already suggested enables, so I suggested the other possibility.  Based on his current response, it looks like enables.  However, this is still a guess as why does the OP have tristates on non-overlapping signals that are likely to be part of an RTL design?

Comment: @Val , Jim Lewis  ,  thank you for you support;  i use this implementation to describe the register SAR logic. for component SA_REG, and SA_REG, I use the strutural descprition using the transistor Nmos and Pmos ,i will put  the code of 2 components, for more details

Comment: @JimLewis The enables are reasonable because of 'z' and what happens when one of the registers is enabled. Nothing is expected at bit 10 that you wrapped into the generate. I do not see the point of doing that. StackOverflow policy implies that answers are useful for the others. You should disclose what you mean by your manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging = reducing the problem to minimum. Regarding VHDL, you can instantiate everything as entity, like

```
U1: entity MY_IMPLEMENTATION port map ()
```

in order to eliminate the need to declare the components everywhere. Instead of declaring the SA_REG and SA_REGDR components, you could expose their implementation.

Your SA_REGDR is stuck at bit 10 whereas N is used for SA_REG instantiations is variable. You are preparing the ground for inconsistency.

The outputs DA(i) are determined by SA_REG and SA_REGDR, whose implementation are kept in secret. We, therefore, cannot answer the question certainly. Yet, 'z' values imply that one of the inputs is [driver enable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic#Output_enable_vs._chip_select). When you increment the inputs, the less significant bit of the inputs switches 0 -> 1 and its driver is enabled so that least significant output bit switches high impendance => concrete value. There is not enough information to explain why do you get 0 in the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit) rather than 1 or anything else.

[Actually, other signals can stay unresolved](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17524/std-logic-or-std-ulogic). Only DA(i) must be std_logic.

Comment: thank you for your clarification , i will put the implementation od sa_REG, and Sa_rREGDR